# Get a 95% confidence interval for Cohen's Kappa in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval, cohens-kappa, agreement-statistics

I've got a study with two radiologist's reading chest x-rays and want to calculate Cohen's kappa of their agreement. The `kappa2` function in the "irr" package and `cohen.kappa` in "psych" can both give me an answer but don't generate a 95% confidence interval. Is there any good way to do this in R as well?

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, but
you may have a real statistical question buried here. 
You may want to edit your question to clarify the underlying 
statistical issue. You may find that when you understand 
the statistical concepts involved, the software-specific elements are 
self-evident or at least easy to get from the documentation.

Comment: The documentation for `cohen.kappa` in psych suggests that it does, in fact, produce $\alpha/2$ confidence intervals.

Comment: A simple way is to use bootstrap. Provide your complete code and I can try working out the bootstrap percentile confidence interval.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have two raters, no missing ratings, and are using the 1960 unweighted kappa, you can calculate the conditional variance using the following formula (see references below):

$$
v = \frac{1-f}{n(1-p_e)^2}\Bigg( p_a(1-p_a)-4(1-\kappa)\Big(\sum_{k=1}^qp_{kk}\hat{\pi}_k-p_a p_e\Big)+4(1-\kappa)^2\Big(\sum_{k=1}^q\sum_{l=1}^qp_{kl}[(p_{Al}+p_{Bl})/2]^2-p_e^2\Big)\Bigg)
$$

This variance estimate can then be used to calculate the bounds of a confidence interval.

$$ CI = \kappa \pm \sqrt{v}\times t_{(1-\alpha/2, n-1)}$$

**References**

Fleiss, J. L., Nee, J. C. M., & Landis, J. R. (1979). The large sample variance of kappa in the case of different sets of raters. *Psychological Bulletin, 86,* 974-977.

Gwet, K. L. (2008). Computing inter-rater reliability and its variance in the presence of high agreement. *British Journal of Mathematical and Statistical Psychology, 61,* 29-48.